Prevent href boxes from overlapping
Issue:
Using a table with cells containing links as followed:
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.5cm} p{2.5cm}}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\href{https://www.google.com}{AAAAAAAAAA}}\\
    \href{https://www.google.com}{BBB} & \href{https://www.google.com}{CCC} \\
\end{tabular}

Result:

Question:
The href rectangle boxes are overlapping, which makes the table cells ugly. How can we avoid this?
My attempt so far
I don't want to hide the rectangles, as in [1], because the reader should easily see which parts of the text are clickable.
I tried to find out the size of the table cells (the link rectangle may cling to this size) by using \frame command, but surprisingly, the link box becomes tighter!
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.5cm} p{2.5cm}}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\frame{\href{https://www.google.com}{AAAAAAAAAA}}}\\
    \frame{\href{https://www.google.com}{BBB}} & \href{https://www.google.com}{CCC} \\
\end{tabular}

Result:

I checked the hyperref package options [2], but saw no indication on how to make the rectangle box tighter!
Environment

TeXstudio 4.8.4
Windows 10 x64 (22H2)

[1] Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks
[2] hyperref

welcome! if you use a distinctive colour for the links, they are clearly clickable but you avoid all the messiness associated with the frames. hyperref has an option to do it this way, though it is not the default.

you can reduce the pdflinkmargin (the default is 1pt):
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\setpdflinkmargin{0.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.5cm} p{2.5cm}}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\href{https://www.google.com}{AAAAAAAAAA}}\\
    \href{https://www.google.com}{BBB} & \href{https://www.google.com}{CCC} \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document} 


another option is to put a box around the link, as the link area follows the surrounding box:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{2.5cm} p{2.5cm}}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\mbox{\href{https://www.google.com}{AAAAAAAAAA}}}\\
    \mbox{\href{https://www.google.com}{BBB}} & \mbox{\href{https://www.google.com}{CCC}} \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document} 


Be aware that link borders are drawn by the pdf reader and are not something that can be fully controlled by LaTeX.

For me, \setpdflinkmargin{0pt} doesn't work. But this \hypersetup{pdflinkmargin=0pt} works. In the latter case, the rectangle boxes are now "touching" (instead of "overlapping" or "away from each other").

The approach \mbox clearly works as wished: the rectangle box is now tighly embracing the text!

Could you please explain why \mbox works? I checked its documentation (link), but it looks like the command is not intended to use in such a way. Maybe a useful side-effect?

when pdftex creates a link it calculates the linkarea relative to the surrounding box, and \mbox creates tighter boxes than tabular cells (which contain a strut). Try e.g. \mbox{\rule[-0.5cm]{0pt}{1cm}\href{https://www.google.com}{AAAAAAAAAA}} to see that this create a larger link area.
